# Module VirtualKeyboard not available in Qt Quick UI-Prototype? Err-Msg: not installed

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, qtvirtualkeyboard

I want to create a Qt Quick UI. So I started a new Qt Quick UI-Prototyp-Project. I got standard template but compilatoin already fails with Err-Message.

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Window 2.15
import QtQuick.VirtualKeyboard 2.15

Window {
    id: window
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    InputPanel {
        id: inputPanel
        z: 99
        x: 0
        y: window.height
        width: window.width

        states: State {
            name: "visible"
            when: inputPanel.active
            PropertyChanges {
                target: inputPanel
                y: window.height - inputPanel.height
            }
        }
        transitions: Transition {
            from: ""
            to: "visible"
            reversible: true
            ParallelAnimation {
                NumberAnimation {
                    properties: "y"
                    duration: 250
                    easing.type: Easing.InOutQuad
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
 file:///.../VKTest/VKTest.qml:12 Type InputPanel unavailable qrc:/QtQuick/VirtualKeyboard/content/InputPanel.qml:127 Type Keyboard unavailable qrc:/QtQuick/VirtualKeyboard/content/components/Keyboard.qml:38 module "QtQuick.VirtualKeyboard.Plugins" is not installed
```

But creating new Qt Quick Application with standard template - equal to UI-Prototype template - compiles fine.

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Window 2.15
import QtQuick.VirtualKeyboard 2.15

Window {
    id: window
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    InputPanel {
        id: inputPanel
        z: 99
        x: 0
        y: window.height
        width: window.width

        states: State {
            name: "visible"
            when: inputPanel.active
            PropertyChanges {
                target: inputPanel
                y: window.height - inputPanel.height
            }
        }
        transitions: Transition {
            from: ""
            to: "visible"
            reversible: true
            ParallelAnimation {
                NumberAnimation {
                    properties: "y"
                    duration: 250
                    easing.type: Easing.InOutQuad
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but with main application:

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    qputenv("QT_IM_MODULE", QByteArray("qtvirtualkeyboard"));

#if QT_VERSION < QT_VERSION_CHECK(6, 0, 0)
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
#endif

    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    const QUrl url(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml"));
    QObject::connect(&engine, &QQmlApplicationEngine::objectCreated,
                     &app, [url](QObject *obj, const QUrl &objUrl) {
        if (!obj && url == objUrl)
            QCoreApplication::exit(-1);
    }, Qt::QueuedConnection);
    engine.load(url);

    return app.exec();
}
```

Does anybody also had this problem or know a reason? I tried it witha clean Ubuntu+QT5.15 (QtVirtaulKeayboard checked) and Windows. Maybe Virtual Keyboard doesn't work with a UI-Prototype?

Comment: what is `UI-Prototype`? Check please that you have `QT += virtualkeyboard` in both of *.pro

Comment: UI-Prototype is a project-type of QT-Creator

Comment: How did you install Qt?

Comment: @eyllanesc Installed via Qt online installer to avoid manuell errors

Comment: @Findus Are you sure you are compiling Qt 5.15 from the online installer? Many times it happens that the user compiled his project with the qt installed from the ubuntu repositories

Comment: Yes, I am sure. I tested on fresh minimal Ubuntu LTS 20 installation an a fresh Qt online installation. Also Ubuntu 20 Qt repository is 5.12. imported Qt 5.15.